# Kendo UI Grid editable manual dataItem.set() slow/delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an editable Kendo Grid that may have a column with a checkbox to change a boolean value. I have used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17923173/1267304) proposed by *OnaBai* that is working perfectly!

The only problem is that the checkbox value change is too slow. When user clicks it, it takes about 1 second to change. I realize that the `dataItem.set()` method is responsible by this delay.

My grid has a considerable amount of data. About 30-40 columns and 300+ lines. It is defined as follows:

```
$("#mainGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,

    pageable: false,
    sortable: true,

    scrollable: true,
    editable: true,
    autoBind: false,
    columnMenu: true, // Cria o menu de exibição de colunas
    height: getGridHeight(),

    toolbar: [/* hide for brevity */],
    columns: [/* hide for brevity */],
    dataBound: function() { /* hide for brevity. */},
    edit: function() { /* hide for brevity. */}
});
```

Another detail is that, when `dataItem.set()` is called, it calls `dataBound()` event but that is not causing the delay. Grid's `edit()` method is not being called on this process. I don't know if worths to post `dataSource` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative way for doing what OnaBai proposed and it's working better.

```
// This is the grid
var grid = $("#mainGrid").data("kendoGrid");

// .flag is a class that is used on the checkboxes
grid.tbody.on("change", ".flag", function (e) 
{
    // Get the record uid
    var uid = grid.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr")).uid;

    // Find the current cell
    var td = $(e.target).parent().parent();

    // This opens the cell to edit(edit mode)
    grid.editCell(td);

    // This ones changes the value of the Kendo's checkbox, that is quickly shown, 
    // changed and then hidden again. This marks the cell as 'dirty' too.
    $(td.find("input")[0]).prop("checked", $(e.target).is(":checked") ? "checked" : null).trigger("change").trigger("blur");
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me.  I get an error that 'template' is null or not an object.  And why get the uid if you aren't using it for anything?  Also, prop is specific to later versions of jQuery and earlier IE versions don't support it, whereas "attr" is universal.  But $(e.target) will only work if you have it in an action function like this, and not with IE (http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventtargetsrcelement.htm).  Setting an attribute like `.setAttribute('id',id)` that is passed in using `${Id}` can then be used to grab the object via jQuery and is universal.

Comment: Also, in my answer, when I tried mixing the `.trigger("change")` with `.blur()`, it didn't like it.  I had to put them on separate lines.

Comment: @vapcguy But I didn't ask anything about .NET here. I don't even use it, only javascript. So your answer in **my** case doesn't help further.

Comment: Uh, it doesn't matter if it's in .NET/MVC/HTML - we ARE talking about the javascript, above. If you don't use the uid for anything, no sense in getting it. `attr` is backwards-compatible with earlier versions of jQuery where `prop` is not. `$(e.target)` is not compatible with IE. You could do `.setAttribute('id',id)` and pass in `id` from `e.id` in the function.  Putting `.trigger("change")` and `.trigger("blur")` on the same line was something that did not work for me - don't know how it did for you. All of this IS about the javascript and nothing I said made it specific to any type of case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the approach from **[this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/checkbox-column-and-incell-editing.aspx)** code library article when it comes to use checkboxes. It does not use the set methods of the model and still works the same way. Even with 2000 records on a single page CheckAll will work flawlessly.

Comment: Sorry but it seems to be the same approach that I'm using. Look at file Index.cshtml line 30. Is the same snippet used on the answer that I have referenced.

Comment: Yes I was referencing the approach used in the CheckAll function, you can see the IsAdmin property is assigned directly (without using the set method) and after that the Grid is refreshed manually.

Comment: I got it - I think. In my case, the assignment is not by the `set()`, the value is parse by the dataSource. This is working great. I'm using the `set()` method only on that code called on the `click` event.

Comment: Please see my answer and tell me if you agree.

Answer (score 0):

Should try something like this:

I'll set the column with the Edit button to look like this:

```
columns.Command(command => {command.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btnEdit_" + "${Id}" }); }).Width(100).Hidden(true);
```

And have it where clicking into the first column (I have an image with a hyperlink) uses an  onclick function to programmatically click the Edit button, click the checkbox, then click the Update button.  Probably more "old school", but I like knowing it is following the order I would be doing if I were updating it, myself.

I pass in the object ("this"), so I can get the row and checkbox when it appears, the new status as 0 or 1 (I have some code that uses it, not really necessary for this demo, though, so I'm leaving that part out of my function for simplicity), and the ID of that item:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Title("Active").Width(100).ClientTemplate("# if (IsActive == true ) {# <a href=javascript:void(0) id=btnActive_${Id} onclick=changeCheckbox(this, '0', ${Id}) class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-update'><img style='border:1px solid black' id=imgActive src=../../Images/active_1.png /></a> #} else {# <a href=javascript:void(0) id=btnActive_${Id} onclick=changeCheckbox(this, '1', ${Id}) class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-update'><img style='border:1px solid black' id=imgActive src=../../Images/active_0.png /></a> #}#");

function changeCheckbox(obj, status, id) {
    var parentTr = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    $('[id="btnEdit_' + id + '"]').click();

    parentTr.childNodes[5].childNodes[0].setAttribute("id", "btnUpdate_" + id); // my Update button is in the 6th column over
    parentTr.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].setAttribute("id", "chkbox_" + id);
    $('[id=chkbox_' + id + ']').click().trigger("change");
    $('[id=chkbox_' + id + ']').blur();

    var btnUpdate = $('[id="btnUpdate_' + id + '"]');
    $('[id="btnUpdate_' + id + '"]').click();

}
```

Code above assumes, of course, the checkbox is in the first column.  Otherwise, adjust the first `childNodes[0]` on that chkbox setAttribute line to the column it sits in, minus one because it starts counting from zero.

Answer (score 0):

I did a solution much like @DontVoteMeDown. But I have a nested grid (master / detail) so I get the parent grid from the event parameter. Also I just trigger a click-event on the checkbox.

```
$("#grid .k-grid-content").on("change", "input.chkbx", function (e) {
    // Get the parent grid of the checkbox. This can either be the master grid or the detail grid.
    var parentGrid = $(e.target).closest('div[data-role="grid"]').data("kendoGrid");
    // Get the clicked cell.
    var td = $(e.target).closest("td");
    // Enter the cell's edit mode.
    parentGrid.editCell(td);
    // Find the checkbox in the cell (which now is in "edit-mode").
    var checkbox = td.children("input[type=checkbox]");
    // Trigger a click (which will toggle check/uncheck).
    checkbox.trigger("click");
});
```