# Why my checkbox resets after dataSource has been synced but incoming data is modified correctly?

Tags: javascript, rest, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm using kendoUi in order to connect via REST API with my backend server. The current goal is to make bool fields available to change right in the grid. I do it in the following way.

```
    function onLoad() {
var Task = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id : "id",
    fields : {
        "id" : { type: "number"},
        "date" : { type: "date"}, 
        "done" : { type: "boolean"},
        "class" : { type: "string"},
        "title" : { type : "string" }
    }
});

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "jsonp",
//    autoSync: true,
    transport: {
       read: "http://localhost:9090/todo-backend/tasks",
       update: {
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
            if (operation === "update") {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            }
            return data;
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: Task
    }
});

var selectedTask;

$("#grid").kendoGrid({ 
     dataSource: dataSource,
     selectable: true,
     columns: [{ field: "done", title: "Done" , template: "<input type='checkbox' class='cb_done' data-bind='checked:done', #= done ? checked='checked' : '' #/>" },
          { field: "title", title: "Task"}],
     change: function() {
         var title;
         this.select().each(function() {
             var dataRow = grid.dataItem($(this));
             title = dataRow.title;
             selectedTask = dataRow;
         })

         this.dataSource.transport.options.update.url= "http://localhost:9090/todo-          backend/tasks/" + selectedTask.id;

         $("#change-title").val(title);
}
});

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

grid.tbody.on("change", ".cb_done", function (e) {
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    item.set("done", $(e.target).is(":checked"));
    dataSource.sync();
});

$("#change-task").click(function() {
    var val = $("#change-title").val();
    selectedTask.set("title", val);
    dataSource.sync();
    dataSource.read();
})

}

window.onload=onLoad;
```

To implement this approach I read: [checkbox binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/checked#using-the-checked-binding-with-a-checkbox), [dataSource.columns](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns), [kendo.data.Model](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889049/adding-bindeable-checkbox-column-to-grid),[this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-add-checkbox-in-grid),[this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/display-boolean-field-as-checkbox)

When i'm trying to sync dataSource() my checkboxes(cb) reset to invalid state. And only after refreshing the page, I can see actual state of tasks. It seems like cb uses initial value on declaration stage of dataSource.columns.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. dataSource.sync() appended to the "tbody.on change" routine. This resolves the problem. Now all is ok. 0_o. Code snippet editted. And still don't know what the reason of such a weird behaviour.